# How to make all docker bind mounts declared by docker-compose :delegated by default?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, volumes

MacOs has performance issues with bind mounts without a :cached or :delegated flags.
My codebase is big and changing all the volumes' declarations is not an option.

Is there a way to make docker automatically consider any bind mount declared without a :consistent or :default flag in all my docker-compose files as a :delegated or :cached ones?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. How about a well defined regex replace for your volume definitions?

Comment: @PierreB. I'm right now considering a full yaml scan, regex looks too scary

Comment: My experience here has generally been that moving things out of bind mounts works better here.  Use named volumes for opaque data stores like your database storage; don't use volumes at all for your application source code (it should be built into the image).